# AngularJs Directive does not intercept the updates of the services

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service

I am trying to implement the directive that is consuming the data from the service and reacts accordingly. However, something is going wrong and I need some assistance.
Here is the sample of the code that also can be found at http://jsfiddle.net/3c9h7/5/

```
 var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
 app.service('MyService', [
    '$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
        this.value = 4;
        var self = this;
        function inc(){
           self.value += 3;
        }
        setInterval(inc, 1000);
    }
  ]);
app.directive('myDir', ['MyService', function(MyService){
    return {
        link : function(scope, element){
            function expr(){
                return MyService.value;
            }
            function react(){
                element.html(MyService.value);
            }
            scope.$watch(expr, react);
            react();
        }
    }
}]);

<div ng-app='myApp'my-dir>
</div>
```

As the result Div element displaying the initial value of MyService.value but is ignoring the updates that happens in the service every second.
I have found the solution which involves rootScope(i.e. uncomment lines 7 and 9 in the jsFiddle sample):

```
function inc(){
    $rootScope.$apply(function(){
        self.value += 3;
    });
}
setInterval(inc, 1000);
```

However, it does seem to be right to me..All the samples I found are not using this trick..So, am I missing something? Is "rootScope" solution appropriate? Maybe there is a better way to achieve the goal?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use Angular's `$interval` ([ref](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.15/docs/api/ng/service/%24interval)) instead of `window.setInterval()`.

What it does though is actually calling `apply()` under the hoods, so your solution is correct, just a bit more complex. Also `$interval` can be mocked for testing.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but in the real code the service is not using setInterval at all..It is using media query listener to modify the internal state, but absolutely the same problem appears there.

Comment: The same principle applies. Angular has no way to know that something has changed, but to compare current values with saved values of watched expressions. Something must trigger this process, and it is the `$apply()` method. Everything provided by Anguler itself (e.g. `$http`, `ng-click` etc...) calls `$apply()` under the hoods. So must your own event handling code, if it is "outside" Angular.

Comment: Okay, I see...do you know any good article/documentation topic/blog post that describes this point in details?